# Save a model and return its' relationships

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, polymorphism

In my codebase I have an Asset model and a Technology model,

The asset model is morphable,

```
public function assetable() {
    return $this->morphToMany();
}
```

And the technology model relates too it,

```
public function asset() {
    return $this->morphOne(Asset::class, 'assetable');
}
```

In my controller I am doing the following,

```
public function create(Request $request) {

    //Do validation

    \DB::beginTransaction();

    try {
        $technology = Technology::create([
            'technology' => $request->name,
            'type' => 'payment'
        ]);
    } catch(\Exception $e) {
        \DB::rollback();
        throw($e);
    }

    try {
        //update the already uploaded asset so it relates to the newly created Technology
        $assets = Asset::whereIn('id', $request->uploadedFile)->update([
            'assetable_id' => $technology->id,
            'assetable_type' => 'App\Payment'
        ]);
    } catch(\Exception $e) {
        \DB::rollback();
        throw($e);
    }

    \DB::commit();
    return response(['technology' => $technology->load('asset')], 201);
}
```

I am wanting to return the new created Technology asset with the asset relation as part of the result, but it returning as null,

What am I doing wrong? Surely I don't need to requry the database?

Comment: You need to re-query the database . `Asset::update([ ... ])` makes the SQL query  `UPDATE assets SET ...` which is not a query that will return the affected rows

Comment: why are you setting the class type of the morph to `App\Payment`? when it tries to load the `asset` relationship it won't be able to for that `Technology` because that `Asset` is not related to it ... that `Asset` is related to some model named `App\Payment` with the same 'id' as that `Technology` though  ... unless `Technology` here is an alias to your `Payment` class?

Comment: @lagbox *facepalm* doh! Thanks buddy!

Answer (score 0):

make relation In Model Technology.php

```
public function asset(){
   $this->hasMany(Asset::class)
}
```

and make relation In Model Asset.php

```
public function technology(){
   $this->belongsTo(Technology::class)
}
```

In Controller

```
public function create(Request $request) {

    //Do validation

    \DB::beginTransaction();

    try {
        $technology = Technology::create([
            'technology' => $request->name,
            'type' => 'payment'
        ]);

        //update the already uploaded asset so it relates to the newly created Technology
        $assets = Asset::whereIn('id', $request->uploadedFile)->update([
            'assetable_id' => $technology->id,
            'assetable_type' => 'App\Payment'
        ]);

    } catch(\Exception $e) {
        \DB::rollback();
        throw($e);
    }

    \DB::commit();
    return response(['technology' => $technology->asset], 201);
}
```